# command to open emacs and emacs calendar and diary in .bash_profile in Mac OS X

Tags: macos, emacs, bash

How do you open the emacs calendar as well as the diary when you start Terminal in Mac OS X with the .bash_profile that I created in my home directory. Any help will be greatly appreciated. Below is my code that I have so far for my .bash_profile:

```
date
emacs
```

Answer (score 0):

This is probably not the best way to do this, but answering your question directly replace the emacs line in .bash_profile with the following:

```
emacs --eval '(progn (calendar) (diary))'
```

Depending on what you're doing, it might be better to include the following lines in your `.emacs`:

```
(calendar)
(diary)
```